# Microsoft.ML and Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, ml.net, microsoft.ml

Does Microsoft.ML work in Xamarin?

I have followed many of the tutorials and videos at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/ml-dotnet.
The simple tutorial ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis)) sets out the core process, which I have followed (in a Xamarin project) but I cannot get an iOS (or Android) Xamarin app to see the `MLModel.zip` file that is produced from Model Builder. It is set to "Copy Always".

Can I do this, or is Microsoft.ML incompatible with Xamarin (for ARM)?

Release notes for ML NET 1.4 (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ml-net-1-4-global-availability-machine-learning-for-net/) suggest that it will run as .NET Core 3.0, and so should be available to ARM processors, but I can find no confirmation or denial of ML.NET's status in relation to Xamarin cross platform development.

Comment: Xamarin [Sample](https://github.com/jimbobbennett/Xam.Plugins.OnDeviceCustomVision) using Core ML

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, ML.NET doesn't work directly in Xamarin just yet. I believe you would have to wait until [MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/) comes out to be able to do that.

I asked this to the team during [an interview](https://youtu.be/3PtS098JOZ8?t=2690) and they said the best thing you can do is to create an API that uses it and use the API within the Xamarin app. I have a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMyf4sdrptM) that shows doing that, if you need.