# Using YOLO on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, object-detection, yolo

I want to use object detection techniques such as YOLO in Xamarin. How can I use something like tflite or pytorch mobile on Xamarin?

If I search "C# Yolo", I can find using C# with YOLO on desktops only.

Answer (score 2):

The YOLO approach has been implemented with [ML.Net](https://rubikscode.net/2021/04/05/machine-learning-with-ml-net-object-detection-with-yolo/), [which does not work in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115682/microsoft-ml-and-xamarin).

Check out these articles if you want to do object detection via a service or on the device:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/using-object-detection-from-inside-your-xamarin-app/
- https://geeks.ms/xamarinteam/2019/07/04/realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-xamarin-android/